# javafx looping while button pressed

Tags: java, javafx

I am having trouble getting this to loop when the button is pressed, and stop looping when the button is released.

```
btnUp.pressedProperty().addListener((observable, wasPressed, pressed) -> {
    System.out.println("changed");
    if (pressed) {
        System.out.println("pressed");
        while(btnUp.isArmed()){ 
            try        
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException ex) 
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            //moveflag = false;
            System.out.println("pressed");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("released");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. don't use Thread.sleep() inside UI operations, it blocks all UI drawing
2. don't use while inside changelistener, just have a separate loop which checks button's state
3. Timelines are best for such loops

   ```
   public void start(Stage stage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Press me");

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
       // this code will be called every second
       System.out.println(btn.isPressed() ? "pressed" : "released");
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();


    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(btn), 300, 250);
    stage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
   ```

   }